# Are the 4 square representations of a sum of 4 squares of an integer equivalent?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

Every integer $N$ can be represented by a sum of 4 squares $N=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$. We usually have more than one representation for a given integer N. For example $7*13=91$ has the following representation written without the exponent 2. $$91=(5,5,5,4),(5,7,4,1),(5,8,1,1),(8,3,3,3),(9,3,1,0)$$

All these representations are equal to the same number but can they be called equivalent if we can transform one into another. We will give just one example. We take the first representation $(5,5,5,4)$ and show that it can be transformed into the second one $(5,7,4,1)$. 
$$5^2=3^2+4^2=4^2+2^2+2^2+1^2=(4,2,2,1)$$ By substituting $(5,5)$ in the first representation by $(4,2,2,1),(4,2,2,1)$, rearranging we get $$(5,5)=4^2+2^2+2^2+1^2+4^2+2^2+2^2+1^2=4^2+4^2+4^2+1^2+1^2=7^2+1^2=(7,1)$$ 
if we now substitute $(5,5)$ by its new value $(7,1)$ into the first representation, we get the second one $(5,7,4,1)$. It is clear that we can take the second representation and transform it into the first.

Is this a general result? Is it possible to transform every representation into every other representation for a given integer $N$, and if yes, can it be proven?

If it is possible to always transform one 4-sq representation into another one, then we do not need to find all the representations because it is expensive to calculate all of them. We would in that case only need the first one, then transform it into another one if needed.

Comment: I am unsure what you count as a valid transformation. Whether it is possibly to apply the four-square theorem to the four squares themselves, permute these sixteen numbers and arrive at the destination tuple?

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear: re-ordering is irrelevant, right? We don't care about $(5, 5, 4, 5)$ nor $(5, 4, 5, 5)$ nor $(4, 5, 5, 5)$?

Comment: You can always write $5^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{5^2} 1^2$ and rearrange

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, any transformation that takes you from one representation to another should be considered valid (in my opinion).

Comment: @Mr.Brooks, yes, re-ordering is irrelevant.

Comment: If any transformation is acceptable, user1952009's answer is sufficient. If you do not think it is sufficient, you should explain why.

Comment: @RossMillikan, I understand that the expansion of a square into a sum of a bunch of 1^2 can be re-arranged into a sum of different squares, some of which may be 1^2. I was hoping for an algorithm that would work for large numbers ( in the 100's of digits ).

Comment: That is an algorithm that works fine for large numbers assuming you know what the target squares are.  There are no computations to do.  If you are looking to find the other representation(s) that is entirely different than your question.  Your question seems to assume we know all the representations and seek to transform one into another.  Please think about what you are asking and make it clear.

Comment: @RossMillikan,  Then my question was misunderstood. I gave an example of how one can transform a 4-sq rep into another. But if it can be proven that one 4-sq rep can always be transformed into another one, then we do not need to find all the 4-sq representations of a given integer N. We simply find the first one and when needed, transform it into another one. It is expensive to find all the 4-sq reps of N but if they are equivalent, if we can transform one into another or the next one, then we only need to find one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're suggesting that a $4$-tuple $[a,b,c,d]$ is equivalent to another $4$-tuple obtained by replacing two of $a,b,c,d$ by some other pair whose sum of squares is the same, the other two remaining unchanged.  Presumably the relation is the transitive closure of this, i.e. if $[a,b,c,d]$ is equivalent to $[a',b',c',d']$ and $[a',b',c',d']$ to $[a'',b'',c'',d'']$ then 
$[a,b,c,d]$ is equivalent to $[a'',b'',c'',d'']$.
But, in your example, $(8,3,3,3)$ is not equivalent to any other solution.

Comment: In fact, I showed that (8,3,3,3) is equivalent to (9,3,1,0) if one does not restrict "replacing two of a,b,c,d by some other pair whose sum of squares is the same, the other two remaining unchanged". We start with $(9,3,1,0)$ and expand $9^2$ into $9^2=(8,3,2,2)$ so $(9,3,1,0)$ becomes $(8,3,2,2,3,1,0)$. But since $(2,2,1)=3^2$, then we end up with $(9,3,1,0)$ transformed into $(8,3,3,3)$.

Comment: It's really unclear to me what is the precise criterion for "equivalence".

Comment: it's just the fact that one representation can be transformed into another one.

Comment: @user25406 That is meaningless unless you specify exactly what transformations are allowed.

Comment: "specifying the transformations that are allowed" was the purpose of this post. The examples provided showed that one representation can be transformed into another if we allow the squares (1, 2, 3 or 4) of the first to be expanded into square themselves and re-assembled to form the final representation. I don't know if starting with one representation, we can get every other representation by those transformations or that the representations form "small groups of various size" where the transformations can be done. I just don't know enough to settle these questions.