# Prove any positive integer can be the summed squares of four special nonnegative integers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Prove any positive integer $n$ can be the summed squares of four special nonnegative integers $a_1, a_2,a_3, a_4$ satisfying both $a_1$ and $a_2+24\cdot a_3$ are perfect squares, such that:  $$n=\sum_{k=1}^4a_k^2$$

The problem [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) can be easily verified for most of the small enough positive integers, but the representation might not be unique. For example:

$$316224^2+1504^2+288^2+192={316224^2+1376^2+672^2+192^2}=10^{11}$$

$${316227^2+693^2+64^2+15^2={316227^2+ 693^2+ 55^2+ 36}^2=10^{11}+99}$$

$${9^2+4^2+1^2+1^2}=8^2+5^2+3^2+1^2=99$$

In order to make it `unique`, we add one more constraint to the four integers: one of the four is a perfect square, and the $a_2+24\cdot a_3$ sum of other two is also a perfect suqare.

Will this continue to hold for :

**Any positive integers that can be represented as the summed square of four nonnegative integers** ; and the representation is not unique.

Comment: You mean at most 4 ,as $1=1^2, 2=1^2+1^2,3=1^2+1^2+1^2$ and $5=2^2+1^2$,etc.

Comment: You might look at "Lagrange's Four-Square Theorem" in Wikipedia.

Comment: I updated it as `nonnegative` integers so as to include those outliers

Comment: So your Q is now exactly Lagrange's 4-Square Theorem.

Comment: And you can find proofs on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem)

Comment: Thank you very much! I updated it with a small constraint so that this becomes an academically hard open question.

Comment: This link shows, though without a formal proof, that the 4 square representations of an integer N are equivalent in the sense that we can transform one into another. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337259/are-the-4-square-representations-of-a-sum-of-4-squares-of-an-integer-equivalent?noredirect=1#comment4817572_2337259